# nestjs+nunjucks how to render async template

Tags: nestjs, nunjucks

I created a layout, and the layout header nav menus data from an api service.
how can I get api service before render the layout.
the layout is includes by every view page

Answer (score -1):

With `ServeStaticModule` you can server every view page

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ServeStaticModule } from '@nestjs/serve-static';
import { join } from 'path';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'client'),
      exclude: ['/api*'],
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I hope it serves you.

View sample full here  https://github.com/yordanisperez/nest/tree/master/sample/24-serve-static